# How we can fetch push notification in background

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am receiving push notification in that payload message i am receiving one URL with message as push notification. but i dont want to show URL to user i want to show only message to user. is it possible from ios side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using url as a separate key in aps then its possible you can display alert only as a message, otherwise any message can't be modify message in background.

```
 "aps": {
        "alert": "alert!",
        "sound": "default",
        "URL"  : "your url"
        }
```

Comment: thanks vinay!! can u plase mark qiestion as + is it in minus plz so taht i can submit more question

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible but it also depend on how you have created your payload but its simple as you create your payload with your link and message, receive at your delegate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushChatObject {
      // get the message value and NSLog is or set to UIAlert or in NSString
      (pushChatObject)[@"Message"];
}
```

Comment: i dont want to show URL in notification when it arraives on phone.

Comment: The payload is dictionary and the url will not show to user until you not get it from payload dictionary and show it to the user

Comment: that means when user will see notification when app is not running then user will able to see that URL or not?

Comment: aha! not i got your point what is confusing you, when app receive notification it show the message on notification bar is the alert message  like 

"aps": {
        "alert": "alert!",
        "sound": "default"
    }

so if you not put your url at alert value it will not show the user, do like the below answer is showing and your are good to go

Comment: see! when app is showing notification i dont want to show URL to user i just want to show message only. like whats app messenger.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you shouldn't, because

> Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is
>   not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that
>   there is new data available.
>   (c) Apple

Specify the notification message as

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "alert!",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "URL": "http://apple.com"
}
```

When you receive the notification in the app just check for your param in the notification dictionary:

```
// Place this method to AppDelegate.m
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
                                         (NSDictionary *)notification {      
    if ([notification objectForKey:@"URL"]) {
        NSString *url = [[notification objectForKey:@"URL"] stringValue];
    }
}
```

Check [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) of Apple's Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more info

Comment: i dont want to shoe URL in notification when it arraives on phone.

Comment: will it hide URL in notification when it comes to device coz your not doing any background task?

Comment: need some chages on server side for payload

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can use Child properties of the alert property, you use 1 argument as a alert and another argument as a url, like:
    "aps": {
        "alert" : {
                    "loc-key" : "ALERT",
                    "loc-args" : [ "Your alert message", "Your url"]
                  },
        "sound": "default"
    }

When the device receives the notification, it uses "ALERT" as a key to look up the associated string value in the Localizable.strings file in the .lproj directory for the current language. Assuming the current localization has an Localizable.strings entry such as this: "ALERT" = "%@";

And later on you can get your url using aps NSDictionary.